# Confused about image sizes generated by Wordpress

Tags: images

1. I have read in other threads in this forum that Wordpress creates three copies of any image you upload each of different dimensions; but on my website it seems to be creating well over 10 copies of each image, of different dimensions (I can see them in cpanel File Manager). I don't understand why it's creating more than 3?
2. None of the copies of the images created by Wordpress are displayed when I view the site in my browser - the original image that I uploaded (or a Litespeed-optimised version of that image) is displayed instead. So what's the point of WP creating the resized images if the browser just ignores them?

Many thanks for your help.

Dave

Comment: Also is there any way to get notified by email if someone replies to my posts? I don't have an RSS feed.

Comment: If you're getting the Litespeed version that's because you've installed a Litespeed/Caching/AutoOptimization plugin - WordPress creates three versions because it doesn't know that you'll be using Litespeed.  Also, your WP install is creating 10 copies of each image either because the third party theme you're using or a third party plugin you're using (probably the theme) is telling WordPress to create them.
If you have an account, you'll get an email when someone replies.

Comment: Hi @Tony Djukic. Many thanks for the clarification. Am I right in concluding from what you say that it's safe to assume that as Litespeed is enabled, none of the resized images that WordPress is creating will ever be used and that I can delete them if I want to without any potential performance hit?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that.  Rather, because Google and other Search Engines prefer you do so, you want to use images that are scaled correctly.  So instead of deleting the images (which WP may at some point attempt to reference and then not be able to find) I'd recommend you look into why Litespeed isn't transferring over and then serving all of the images.  So whether it's a plugin or your host, the problem here isn't with what WordPress is doing but rather with what Litespeed isn't doing.

Answer (score 0):

It costs very little to generate as many images as you can imagine as long as the server do not time out when you upload them, which is why wordpress does it. Cost of disk space is very low therefor there is very little point in trying to optimize for it.

Generating images on the fly only when needed, which might sound as a better approch turns out to be more complex on the software side and in the past when it was badly implemented it also created security holes. This do not mean that it is impossible to implement, just that the current implementation is thought of as good enough and there is not a big enough percived "gain" to do the extra effort to implement it.

As for the number of images, in addition to the wordpress core sizes which are intended towards inclusion of images in the content, each theme (and rarely plugins) can also specify that they need specific image sizes to be generated and this is why you get so many images.

As for "generated images are not used", this is a bold claim which is hard to prove. For sure they are used in the admin, and even if you have some plugin which manipulates images before they are served to the user, unless you know exactly how it works it might use the already generated images for that.

Comment: HI @Mark Kaplun

Comment: HI @Mark Kaplun

I don't understand your last paragraph. If you go to https://jackieradophotography.com/ and get the properties of any of the images in any browser, the fileseizes and dimensions of the images being displayed are those of the original images I uploaded. I could give hundreds of examples, but here's one. Near the top of the Home page, on the right, there's a photo of Jackie. 

CONTINUED IN NEXT COMMENT DUE TO CHARACTER LIMIT

Comment: If you use an extension such as Chrome's View Image Info extension to get it's properties, you will see that it's at https://jackieradophotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/JRP-Profile-1.jpg.webp, that it has a file size of 139.21k and dimensions of 1954 x 2443 px - which on my PC is scaled to 304 x 380 px. 

But in ccPanel I can see that Wordpress has created the following versions of the file, all of which have much smaller dimensions and filesizes than the one that my browser is displaying:

CONTINUED IN NEXT COMMENT DUE TO CHARACTER LIMIT

Comment: https://jackieradophotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/JRP-Profile-1-768x960.jpg.webp (30k)
https://jackieradophotography.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/07/JRP-Profile-1-500x625.jpg.webp (15k)

(Among others). So why are all browsers I've checked displaying the  original 1954 x 2443 px version of the image and scaling it 304 x 380 px on my PC, when Wordpress has produced much smaller images for it to use, which are still larger than required? On higher res screens the same 1954 x 2443 px image is displayed but  it is scaled by less. On lower res screens the same image is scaled by more.

Comment: None of the images that WordPress created are being displayed in any browser, even though it would make the site a lot faster if they were bring..

Comment: You say that they are not displayed, that doesn't mean they can not be displayed.... just that you don't know where to check for it. Anyway, you can probably use a plugin to remove versions you are not interested having (or all of them if you are sure about them not being used anywhere).

Comment: Hi Mark

I don't understand your first sentence. Where should I be checking for it? And why would my browsers say they are displaying a different and larger file than the one they are displaying? I'm also confused about your second sentence - I gave you an example of why I don't think they are being displayed by my browser but if you know that they are, please could you let me know how you can tell?

Comment: Dave, you asked a question you got an answer.... If you want to know why your site behaves in a specific way it will have to be inspected and analyzed. Wordpress core can use 3 sizes when inserting images into the content and a thumbnail which might be used in the admin in various places. Other sizes will depend on the theme and plugins you use and where they are used depends on the specific theme and plugins